# Unity Build Different From Editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my editor when I run it starts off with a tutorial screen, However when I build my game it completely skips that part and goes to the tap to start screen. It used to work completely fine until my game crashed and it reset the progress I made on the tutorial screen. I completely redid the tutorial screen and now I cannot get it to work in the final build.

I am trying to find the output log, Now I have a bunch of yellow errors that are saying every single game object is not assigned. They are all assigned in my editor but they still say it isn't. I am not sure how to go about this.

I have restarted my computer, re imported all assets.

Comment: can you give us the exact error?

Comment: Assets\Scripts\PlayerMovement.cs(84,18): warning CS0649: Field 'PlayerMovement.normalScoreText' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null

Comment: There is about 120 of those errors, I understand those errors completely, But it doesnt make any sense because they are not null..

Comment: is the variable public?

Comment: Everything is how it should be. This was working perfectly fine until it crashed and I had to remake a part. The game works fine in the editor, however when I build it the tutorial is skipped.

Comment: what works fine in the editor? the tutorial itself or from start to finish (from the starting screen to the scene after the tutorial)?

Comment: The whole game works completely fine. Then I build to my phone, The tutorial screen that is there in the editor when you start the game is completely gone. The whole game still works on my phone, Except the tutorial is missing.

Comment: Is it an android device? if so, i suggest using Unity Remote 5

Comment: I do, and it works fine, However something when I build deletes that tutorial and I dont know why.

Comment: So I did some things now I have one error message only and its from my save system. NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
PlayerMovement.LoadPlayer () (at Assets/Scripts/PlayerMovement.cs:421)
PlayerMovement.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/PlayerMovement.cs:164)

Comment: Okay now those errors disappeared. I dont even know anymore, I feel like my unity editor is so fucked after that crash.

Comment: I'm just going to do a tutorial button to skip all of this. I didnt want to have to do that but I guess its so broken there is no fix. Thank you.

Comment: this `warning CS0649: Field 'PlayerMovement.normalScoreText' is never assigned to` is just a warning .. you can ignore it if you are sure that the script works how it should. Usually c#/VS doesn't understand that serialized fields are assigned via the Unity inspector and will not be the default value. The other one **is** an error and somewhere you are missing a reference to an object

Comment: Couldn't it be just that you didn't add the scenes in your Build settings ? Only scenes from there will be built

Comment: This is not a different scene sadly. And yes derHugo that is what it means, however its not the case because that part of my code actually works and it is assigned. My whole Unity got screwed up in the crash. I just did a work around and had a button call the tutorial sequence instead of starting on start. It works at least.

Comment: Do you store user progress (which then determines whether the tutorial will show) using e.g. PlayerPrefs? If so, try to ensure that both in-Editor and Build version either use the same PlayerPrefs, or delete both of their PlayerPrefs -- like by calling PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll() right at the start.

Comment: I store user progress using the binary formatter type thing, followed a brackeys tutorial.